# I want to create series data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to create series data in SQL for my testing purpose.

Ex.

```
Product1
Product2
Product3
.
.
.
Product1000
```

I want to create 1000 records like above manner in SQL.
Can anybody suggest me the solution ?

Thank you

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff for the correction. I am using SQL Server 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that via `recursive` way if you are working with SQL Server:

```
with series as (
       select 1 as id
       union all
       select id+1
       from series 
       where id < 1000
)
select concat('Product', id)
from series s
option (maxrecursion 1000);
```

Comment: Won't it be slow performance-wise if we go in the range million records?

Comment: @ChaosLegion, yes, it will be slow like a WHILE loop. In SQL Server, a set-based query could be used for the task but we don't know what DBMS the need is for.

Comment: @DanGuzman. .  It is for `SQL Server` that specify in comment.

Comment: @ChaosLegion . . . Eh.  The overhead of the insert is probably greater than the overhead of adding one more record to the recursive CTE.  Of course, I might be wrong, but with an `insert` happening, there is more overhead.

Comment: Do be careful using a recursive like this. It can end up with performance as slow as or possibly even slower than a while loop. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Answer (score 1):

Just another option using an ad-hoc tally table

**Example**

```
Select Top 1000 Product=concat('Product',Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL))) 
 From  master..spt_values n1
```

**Returns**

```
Product1
Product2
Product3
Product4
...
Product998
Product999
Product1000
```

Comment: `spt_values` doesn't exist in Azure SQL Database. Although that's a non-issue here, using it in production code can block migrations.

Comment: @DanGuzman Then any table of appropriate size will do.  Notice the order by is independent

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(
    Products VARCHAR(15)
);

DECLARE @counter INT
SET @counter = 1
WHILE (@counter <= 1000)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @temp
VALUES('Product'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),@counter));
SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
SELECT * FROM @temp;
```

Comment: For which dbms is this?

Comment: SQL Server. There was no database tag in the question.

Comment: Which makes it even more important to specify dbms, since that code is very product specific.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

```
DECLARE @table table (Product varchar(200))

DECLARE @cnt INT; SET @cnt = 0
WHILE @cnt <=10
BEGIN
SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
insert into @table
SELECT 'Product' +CAST(@cnt as varchar(150))

END

select * from @table
```

Answer (score 0):

A set-based CTE can generate test data quickly. Even better would be a tally (a.k.a.) numbers table.

```
WITH 
     t10 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t1k AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS num FROM t10 AS a CROSS JOIN t10 AS b)
SELECT 'Product' + CAST(num AS varchar(10))
FROM t1k;
```